# why unable to debugging mode to javascript function from aspx file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I will write one simple JavaScript function in inside the ASPX source file.i will write keyword debugger inside function but click update button Can't hit to debugger.

just click update button ,I want to hit debugger in JavaScript  function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

        function update() {

            debugger;

            if (document.getElementById('<%=TxtRStateName.ClientID%>').value == "") {
                alert("Please Enter State Name");
                document.getElementById("cphContentBody_TxtRStateName").focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (!isNaN(document.getElementById("cphContentBody_TxtRStateName").value)) {
                alert("Please Enter Character");
                document.getElementById("cphContentBody_TxtRStateName").value = ""
                document.getElementById("cphContentBody_TxtRStateName").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (document.getElementById("cphContentBody_ImgBtnUpdate").value == "") {
                if (confirm("Do you want to Update?"))

                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly where you're placing the breakpoint: IDE or DevTools, but I suggest using dev tools. I find that IDE debuggers for JS are a hassle to deal with

Comment: Also, your code has syntax errors. I'd suggest you fix them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using IE to test this and believe that the Javascript debugging is disabled there. Follow below steps to check and enable.

1. Click on Tools -> Internet Options
2. Click on Advanced Tab in the popup window
3. Check and see if "Disable Script Debugging" checkbox is checked and uncheck that

Comment: k Thanks.IE Is Work Fine.but Chrome and Firefox not this settings options

Comment: There will be one more option available just below this which would be enabling for other browsers

Comment: Thanks.i will check chrome and firefox but no use.IE only that setting there ,so enable script Debugging options.

Comment: In IE only when you open the same Advanced Tab, just below this "Disable script Debugging" option, there would be one more checkbox for other enabling browsers also. Please check.

Answer (score -1):

- Internet Explorer 8 (Developer Tools - F12). Anything else is second
  rate in Internet Explorer land
- Firefox and Firebug. Hit F12 to display.
- Safari (Show Menu Bar, Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop menu
  bar)
- Google Chrome JavaScript Console (F12 or (Ctrl + Shift + J)). Mostly
  the same browser as Safari, but Safari is better IMHO.
- Opera (Tools -> Advanced -> Developer Tools)

Mark answer if it helps

Comment: good.but i  set break point and debug  for  javascript function inside the aspx file.i don't want browser side debug.

Comment: Just type debugger; where you want to break the JS code. JS not support breakpoints.run your application in chrome and press F12.Then click update button the debugger mode starting automatically.